# Having trouble configuring homebrew to run pure-ftpd as a service

Tags: homebrew, launchd, plist, ftp

I am trying to run pure-ftpd 1.0.46 as a service and have configured my plist file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.pure-ftpd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/pure-ftpd/sbin/pure-ftpd</string>
      <string>-A</string>
      <string>-E</string>
      <string>-j</string>
      <string>-z</string>
      <string>-l</string>
      <string>puredb:/usr/local/etc/pureftpd.pdb</string>
      <string>-I</string>
      <string>1</string>
      <string>-c</string>
      <string>1000</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/pure-ftpd.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/pure-ftpd.log</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

However, I find that whenever I try running as a service it logs the following errors.

pure-ftpd: invalid option --
pure-ftpd: unrecognized option `--j -z'
Unable to start a standalone server: Permission denied

Can anyone identify an error I've made in my plist file?

I tried to confirm it matched the example in SirPavlovas answer provided here : [Getting launchd to read program arguments correctly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110644/getting-launchd-to-read-program-arguments-correctly?newreg=2717f590242f440dad59754df1cd3663)

Comment: How do you wanna run pure-ftpd?

Comment: As a service (though homebrew), the flags indicated above are the flags I would like to pass in terms of customising its behaviour. Passing the above flags directly to pure-ftpd when executing directly works, but I have been unable to get a plist file working.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this trouble or similar, use the command line `plutil` to get feedback on what the plist file problems are (e.g. line numbers). In my case the copy from the Confluence page I used to document the install guide inserted broken whitespace characters, invisible to the naked eye but affecting launchd.