# I need help translating this cron job into launchd

Tags: terminal, launchd, cron, xml

How do achieve the following cron job into launchd xml format?:

```
* * * * * date > /Users/mariano/cron_test.log
```

I've been trying in several ways, but I don't seem to be getting the `ProgramArguments` right. I guess that the `>` might be interfering with the xml tags or something.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’m not aware of a converter that ships with Mac, but perhaps this ruby tool can assist in making a correct list to handle the command syntax - https://github.com/kcrawford/launchd_tools - portion of this.

Comment: For the file handling alone, this might help and the OP there documents some of the time options as a bonus. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217456/5472

Comment: Hello @bmike! And thanks for replying. I have edited my title, sorry for the confusion. I need help translating that cron job on launchd plist format.
**However,** the tool you just posted looks very interesting and quite promising! Thanks!

Comment: No worries - Editing things here is a super power! There’s so much we don’t know about your skill level, this could go in several directions. launchAgents and Daemons are [many times more complicated than cron](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/110644/5472) - so don’t stress if you have several yak shaving moments.

Comment: Thanks again @bmike! Yeah, I can totally see how more complicated it is, haha! But I am trying to learn it as much as I can.  My skill level is advanced n00b perhaps? I think that in this case (and thanks to the Ruby tool you provided), seems like the issue is the outputting using the `>`, that seems to break the program parameters. My aim is to run a launchdaemon that checks a parmeter (for example the date) and outputs results to a log.  Maybe I am better off with `crontab`and not `launchd`? Hoping you can guide me and thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is use an App called [LaunchControl](https://soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/). It saves having to do the details of a plist.  It also can generates the correct StartInterval from a cron time specification. There is also [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/). Both these are commercial and cost money. LaunchControl also describes what each possible key in the plist does.

In this case the keys that you need are

- Program - best to use the full path here and also in cron
- StandardOutPath - to say where the output should go - dealing with your > issue.
- StartCalendarInterval - to say when it runs

The plist generated by Launch Control is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/bin/date</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/cron_test.log</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict/>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thank you @mmmmmm! This is what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks yet again @mmmmmm! for the tip on how to make it run every minute. I guess I will have to continue reading on Launchd and it's syntax.